# Why is os.path.basename() making my HTPC script fail?

Tags: python

Full script here: http://pastebin.com/d6isrghF

I'll admit I'm ***very*** new to Python so please forgive my stupidity if this is an easy question to answer. The section in question is this:

```
sourcePath = jobPath
while os.path.basename(sourcePath):
    if os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(sourcePath)).lower() == category.lower():
        break
    else:
        sourcePath = os.path.dirname(sourcePath)
if not os.path.basename(sourcePath):
    print "Error: The download path couldn't be properly determined"
    sys.exit()
```

jobPath is being fed to the script from sabnzbd and is:

```
/mnt/cache/.apps/sabnzbd/complete/name.of.folder
```

category is:

```
tv
```

So I guess my question is: why is this failing with the error?

Comment: By "_the error_" you mean outputting "`Error: The download path couldn't be properly determined`"?

Comment: Tadeck and Rohan: Yes, the error is "Error: The download path couldn't be properly determined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it does not work

Your code cannot work because `while` is executed until `os.path.basename(sourcePath)` is not evaluated to `True`, then `if` statement is called, which (because it looks like: `if not os.path.basename(sourcePath)`) is obviously evaluated as `True` and thus the message (your "error") is shown:

### Annotated source code

```
sourcePath = jobPath

# This is executed until os.path.basename(sourcePath) is evaluated as true-ish:
while os.path.basename(sourcePath):
    if os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(sourcePath)).lower() == category.lower():
        break
    else:
        sourcePath = os.path.dirname(sourcePath)

# Then script skips to the remaining part, because os.path.basename(sourcePath)
# has been evaluated as false-ish (see above)

# And then it checks, whether os.path.basename(sourcePath) is false-ish (it is!)
if not os.path.basename(sourcePath):
    print "Error: The download path couldn't be properly determined"
    sys.exit()
```

### When (and why) it sometimes works

It *sometimes* works only because category is found in the path, which means `while` loop will be exited (using `break`) even despite still meeting criteria (the condition after `while` keyword: `os.path.basename(sourcePath)`). Because the condition from `while` loop is still met (we exited the loop even though it was met), the next statement's condition (`not os.path.basename(sourcePath)`) is no longer met and the message ("the error") is not printed.

### Possible solutions

I believe one of the solutions is to add a counter to your code, that will print the error only if in specific number of iterations you will not be able to find what you needed. You can also try to catch "too many recursions" exception (if you will use recursion, of course, but the error will be like this: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`).

However, you should redesign it rather to meet your own needs.

Comment: Setting the download directory to include the category fixes it! What a silly error to make. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @EliGreenberg: See the section called "_When (and why) it sometimes works_", it actually mentions why it works when the category is found in the path. But it will fail 100% times when the category is not in the path. In other words there is a place for improvement. Also you may like to actually throw an exception (which is better for debugging purposes), that you can still catch outside the function, if needed (which is good for building reusable library).